# Run C-executable from SD card on Termux

Tags: external-sd, file-permissions, termux

I have just installed `termux` in my Android 6 phone and have given storage permissions so I can read, write or compile from the terminal in the folder `/sdcard/myC/` by using `clang -o birthday birthday.c -lm`. However, when I try to run the executable, I get `-bash: ./birthday: Permission denied`.

I have tried compiling and running in multiple places, i.e. `/sdcard/data/com.termux`, and have tried the command `termux-setup-storage` that ensures the permissions are granted to read/write. I have tried to `chmod` the program as well.

I should be doing something wrong because apparently, the app is really good.

Comment: You cannot run programs from the SD card, as it is mounted with the `noexec` flag. See e.g. [this answer](/a/45564/16575).

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got it to work. Programs can only be run if they are located at the home directory of `termux`. That is, run `pwd` to know where the home directory is and put the source files there, then compile and run, enjoy!

Comment: It is not necessary to put source there, just the binary. Of course you can just copy the binary afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Files store on `/sdcard` cannot have execution permission on android.

You can copy the binary generated to `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/directory/of/your/choice`.

Then make it executable by using `chmod`

Or, you can use [this](https://github.com/GyanPrakash2483/binrun) program to do that for you.

Usage:

```
binrun <your executable> <arguments...>
```

Ps: I made that program